# Is there any keyboard shortcut to add @SuppressWarnings on class in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, development-environment, suppress-warnings

Is there any shortcut for `@SuppressWarnings({"unused", "WeakerAccess"})`

Specially on java classes?

Comment: Why not just globally disable those hints/warnings if you don't care about them?

Comment: You can record a macro (look under Edit -> Macros) and then map it to any key you like (File -> Settings... -> Keymap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a [Live Template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/live-templates.html) which you would then engage by typing the template short name and hitting `TAB`.

Here's an example:

[image]

With this live template you can enter `unused + TAB` and IntelliJ will auto complete to `@SuppressWarnings({"unused", "WeakerAccess"})`